# Gmail API: 400 bad request when trying to use a Service Account (Python)

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api

I had this working fine using a web browser to authenticate the user. However I'm planning on hosting the script on a server with no browser so I need to use a Service Account).

I have followed the instructions listed here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount

I feel I am close but I am getting an error when trying to list (or get) labels (this code worked before I changed it to a Service Account.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from httplib2 import Http
import sys,os
from apiclient.discovery import build
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
import messagebird
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Quickstart'

def main():
     credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    'my_file.json', scopes=SCOPES)

    delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('myemail@address.com')
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http_auth)

    response = service.users().labels().list(userId='myemail@address.com').execute()
    labels = response['labels']
    for label in labels:
        print ('Label id: %s - Label name: %s' % (label['id'], label['name']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error is is on the line:

```
response = service.users().labels().list(userId='myemail@address.com').execute()
```

This is the error I am getting

> HttpError 400 when requesting
>   https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/myemail@address.com/labels?alt=json
>   returned "Bad Request"

However I do feel I am close because if I look on my dashboard on https://console.developers.google.com I can see the requests listed under errors and it even shows if I am requesting a list or get method.

I think I also have some unneeded code as I am trying to adapt from what I had before and not sure what to remove.

Comment: Does it work if you change `http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())` to `http_auth = delegated_credentials.authorize(Http())`?

Comment: Yes it does :-), Thank you. Google should change the documentation as there's states the incorrect version. Thanks again.

Comment: I found a feedback form on their developer page and informed Google of the error.

Comment: I get "AttributeError: 'Http' object has no attribute 'authorize'" if I try to build  method with `http_auth`